# Find the exact value of $\cos(11\pi/12)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

This question I look at as being similar to $\sin(7\pi/12)$.  You can break it up using the special triangles into $3\pi/12 + 4\pi/12$.  However with this one, I can't find one of the angles in which to use.  Perhaps there is another method that I am not seeing, if someone could help me that'd be much appreciated!

Comment: $ \cos \left ( \frac {11 \pi}{12} \right ) = \cos \left ( \pi - \frac \pi {12} \right )$, apply double angle formula: $2\cos^2 (x) - 1 = \cos (2x) $, where $ 2x = \frac {\pi}{6} $

Comment: So you are wondering about the $165$ degree angle, which is $120+45$. Or if you prefer $135+30$.  Or if you prefer $225-60$.

Comment: Use $11 \pi /12 = 3\pi/12 + 8\pi/12$

Comment: $-\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{2\sqrt{2}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$$
$$\cos\frac{11\pi}{12}=\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=\cos(3\pi/4)\cos(\pi/6)-\sin(3\pi/4)\sin(\pi/6)$$
Now you can use special right triangles to find the values of those trigonometric functions.

Comment: How did you get these values (3pi/4 + pi/6)?

Comment: @Ash  Observe that $\frac{3\pi}{4} = \frac{9\pi}{12}$ and that $\frac{\pi}{6} = \frac{2\pi}{12}$.

Comment: $$11\pi/12=9\pi/12+2\pi/12=3\pi/4+\pi/6$$

Comment: Okay, so when doing these questions I need to find two values in which add up to 11  and fit within the /12 interval? I'm just trying to figure out a way for me to be able to understand this so to make it much more obvious what the answer is.  Because there are a lot of combinations that can add up to 11 with the cos (A+B) form.  Must these values also work with the unit circle?

Comment: That is correct.  Yes, they must work with the unit circle.  Choosing $10\pi/12$ and $\pi/12$ will not help you since you would first have to determine the sine can cosine of $\pi/12$.

Comment: |Alright.  So to note some steps for doing these kinds of question, should the first thing I do is look to the unit circle? If you could explain the process of these in a few steps that would help me a lot :)

Comment: This is what I do:
Break the angle into the form $a \frac{\pi}{4}+b\frac{\pi}{6}$, then use sin/cosine addition formulae. Then, use the unit circle to find the values of the sine and cosine functions obtained from the addition formula.

Comment: Okay so it becomes cos3pi/4cospi/6-sin3pi/4sinpi/6, no these angles need to be converted using the trig ratios and the special triangles.  I'm not sure about this next point.  (ex cospi/4= 1/root2).

Answer (score 0):

More generally, for integers $a$ and $b \ne 0$, $\cos(a \pi/b)$ is one of the roots of $T_b(z) - (-1)^a$, where $T_b$ is the $b$'th Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind.  Of course, so are $\cos(a' \pi/b)$ for all other integers $a'$ such that $a - a'$ is even.

In this case, $$T_{12}(z)  = 2048\,{z}^{12}-6144\,{z}^{10}+6912\,{z}^{8}-3584\,{z}^{6}+840\,{z}^{4}
-72\,{z}^{2}+1$$ and
$T_{12}(z) + 1 $ factors as $2\, \left( 2\,{z}^{2}-1 \right) ^{2} \left( 16\,{z}^{4}-16\,{z}^{2}+1
 \right) ^{2}
$.  Since it's not one of the roots of $2 z^2 - 1$ (i.e. $\pm 1/\sqrt{2}$, which are $\cos(\pi/4)$ and $\cos(5\pi/4)$), it's one of the roots of $16 z^4 - 16 z^2 + 1$.  Those roots are $\pm \sqrt{6}/4 \pm \sqrt{2}/4$.  Numerical
approximation shows it must be $-\sqrt{6}/4 - \sqrt{2}/4$.

Answer (score 0):

I got:

$$cos(\frac{11 \pi}{12})=-\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{2}}$$

Proof the equality from above:

1. Multiply numerator and denominor by:

$$\frac{1}{-1-\sqrt{3}}$$

$$\frac{1}{\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{-1-\sqrt{3}}}=-\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{2}}$$

2. Than you get 1=1!
3. You get:

$$\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{-1-\sqrt{3}}=\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{-1-\sqrt{3}}$$

Therefore:

$$cos(\frac{11 \pi}{12})=-\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that ${\displaystyle {11 \pi \over 12} = {1 \over 2} {11 \pi \over 6}}$, and that ${\displaystyle \cos {11 \pi \over 6} = {\sqrt{3} \over 2}} $. Hence by the half-angle formula
$$\cos {11 \pi \over 12} = \pm \sqrt{ 1 + \cos {11 \pi \over 6} \over 2}$$
We take the negative sign here since ${\displaystyle {11 \pi \over 12}}$ is in the second quadrant. The above simplifies to
$$= -\sqrt{ 1 + {\sqrt{3} \over 2}\over 2}$$
$$= -{\sqrt{ 2 + {\sqrt 3}} \over 2}$$
Although in a different form, this is the same as the other answers.